# Issue With Pagination link from Instagram API

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, instagram

This is my first time working with pagination. The issue I am having is that I am getting multiple responses from the Instagram API after a certain amount of clicks to the pagination button. I think I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that the function is probably firing multiple times. Take a look at  my functions.

Receives the data and sorts  it to the other functions:

```
function sortAndStore(data) {

    var images = data.data,
        pagLink = data.pagination.next_url;

    var newImages = [];

    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var link = images[i].link,
            standardRes = images[i].images.standard_resolution.url,
            thumb = images[i].images.thumbnail.url;

        var tempImages = new Object();

        tempImages.link = link;
        tempImages.standard_res = standardRes;
        tempImages.thumbnail = thumb;

        newImages.push(tempImages);

    }

    createLayout(newImages);

    loadMore(pagLink);

}
```

Creates the desired layout (sloppy right now but working):

```
function createLayout(data) {
    var images = data;

    if ($('#authorizeInsta').css('display') === 'inline') {

        $('#authorizeInsta').hide();
        // Adds additonal structure
        $('<div id="instagramFeed" class="row-fluid" data-count="0"></div>').insertAfter('.direct_upload_description_container');

    }

    if (!$('#feedPrev').length > 0) {
        $('<ul id="feedNav" class="pagination"><li><a id="feedPrev" href="#">Prev</a></li><li><a id="feedNext" href="#">Next</a></li></div>').insertAfter('#instagramFeed');
    }

    var count = $('#instagramFeed').data('count'),
        countParse = parseInt(count);
        newCount = countParse + 1;

    $('<div id="row' + newCount + '" class="span3">').appendTo('#instagramFeed');
    $('#instagramFeed').data('count', newCount);


    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

        var link = images[i].link,
            standardRes = images[i].standard_res,
            thumb = images[i].thumbnail,
            newImage = '<img data-image="' + standardRes + '" src="' + thumb + '" class="feedImage" id="feedImage' + i + '"/>';

        $(newImage).appendTo('#row' + newCount + '');

    }

    imageSelect();
}
```

Pagination function:

```
function loadMore(link) {

    var pagLink = link;

    console.log(pagLink);

    $('#feedPrev').unbind('click').click(function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        })
            .done(function(data) {
                sortAndStore(data);
            })
            .fail(function(data, response) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(response);
            });

        return false;
    });

}
```

I understand that the issue is probably here in the sortAndStore function

```
createLayout(newImages);

loadMore(pagLink);
```

And here is what the pagination link console logs out to. The issue being that I clicked the button three times and I got four responses. The first two times were fine. I got one pagination link, but the third time I received two response.

[image: pagLink variable console log]

If you can see a different issue or suggest a different way to structure my functions it would be greatly appreciated. The data parameter in the sortAndStore function is the data from the original Instagram API call.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! The issue was that every time the pagination button was clicked the browser was storing a new value for pagLink. Therefore, after clicking the button twice, there were two stored variables which made two pagination API calls.

The fix is to redefine the variable every time a new pagination link goes through the function, not to define an additional pagLink variable.

So this:

```
function sortAndStore(data) {

    var images = data.data;
    pagLink = data.pagination.next_url;
```

Instead of this:

```
function sortAndStore(data) {

    var images = data.data,
        pagLink = data.pagination.next_url;
```

So the solution was to redefine the variable, not to add an additional one, like I was doing by accident.